# jvm stack threads increase

Tags: multithreading, timer, jvm

There are  many Timer threads in my jvm. From thread dump, i get this:

```
"Timer-19" - Thread t@159
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <134c08ad> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:483)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

In my program i don't use Timer, it confused me a lot. 
So please help!

Answer (score 2):

1. attach a debugger
2. set a breakpoint on the `Timer` constructor
3. wait until it triggers
4. inspect the call stack to find the caller